# Can I add a field in SQL backend tables and use it on Forms in Access frontend?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have recently migrated a Access database to SQL 2012. Now the users want a new field on the Form on the front end which is Access. I was able to add columns on the Access end. But, I cannot see or use it on the Access Front End. What am I missing?

Comment: "I was able to add columns on the Access end" - do you mean SQL Server?

Comment: This question was tagged as MySQL - presumably that was an error?